# Is difference of convex hulls a convex hull of differences?

Tags: geometry, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, polytopes

Let $K \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be an n-dimensional simplex. Let $e_i$ denote the $i^{th}$ standard unit vector. Define $K-K$ as follows:
$$
K-K=\{x-y: x,y \in K\}
$$
We know that $K=$ convex hull $\{e_1, e_2,\ldots, e_n , (0,0,0,...,0)\}$.

I am wondering if $K-K=$ convex hull of $ \{e_1,e_2,\ldots, e_n, (0,0,...,0) \} - \{e_1,e_2,\ldots, e_n, (0,0,...,0) \}$

This seems to be true for n=2 case.

Comment: As I understood, you ask whether $K-K$ is also a convex set ?

Comment: Aaha, I think I understood your question

Comment: Apply the [identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_addition#Convex_hulls_of_Minkowski_sums) $\text{conv}(A+B)=\text{conv}(A)+\text{conv}(B)$.

Comment: For a proof of the identity .@A.G. mentioned, cf: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/587162/prove-convex-hull-of-minkowski-sum

Comment: @user251257: Thanks a lot. I forgot the simple identity

Comment: @A.G: Thanks. I failed to figure out this simple observation.